# Why does the Animation not work on mouse scroll in IE but works with smoothscrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling, animate.css

I have a bit of a problem.  I'm using Animate.css and jquery to make my animation fade in when the scroll gets to where the animated div is.  Unfortunately it is not working great.  It works in FireFox and it works in IE when I hit a button that uses smooth scrolling to the div but if I use the mouse wheel or use the scroll bar it will not fire off the animation, leaving a blank space.

Here is my javascript:

```
// Smooth Scrolling
 $(document).ready(function(){
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
 $('.hashscroll').on('click', function(event) {

// Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
 if (this.hash !== "") {
  // Prevent default anchor click behavior
  event.preventDefault();

  // Store hash
  var hash = this.hash;

  // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
  // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
  $('html, body').stop(true, false).animate({
    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
  }, 800, function(){

    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
    window.location.hash = hash;
  });
  } // End if
 });
 });

// Detect for animation
$(document).ready(function() {
// Check if element is scrolled into view
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
// If element is scrolled into view, fade it in
$(window).scroll(function() {
$('.down .animated').each(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
    $(this).addClass('fadeInDown');
    $(this).removeClass('block');
  }
});
});
    $(window).scroll(function() {
$('.left .animated').each(function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
    $(this).addClass('fadeInLeft');
    $(this).removeClass('block');
  }
});
});
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 0px; text-align: center; left: 0; width: 100%; z-index: 3"><a class="hashscroll" href="#wrapper1">
 <img src="assets/img/ArrowTallSmooth.gif" width="2%"/>  
 </a></div>

<div id=wrapper1>
 <div class="down"> 
 <div class="block animated">
    <p>Welcome to Station 2! It guides you through the numerous data inputs required by the LIC DSF Excel template and will help you understand how to do the following: </p>
                                  </div>  
          </div>

  <div class="left">                   
  <div class="block animated">
            <p>More Content</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click on the image and use smoothscrolling it works in IE but if I use the mouse wheel or use the bar on the side it does not fire.

Appreciate your assistance!